# Regex extract number before text (various text combinations)

Tags: php, regex

need a bit of help with regex (php). I have the following text:

11 hours 30 secs 12 mins

and

12 mins 11 hours 30 secs

and

12 minutes 11 hours 30 secs

I would like to extract the no. before mins the regex should work with all text combinations.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to capture _any_ time there is digits, a space, and then "mins" or "minutes", or only in the case when it is next to "hours" and "secs" as well?

Comment: @derekv Sorry if it wasn't clear I wanted just the value before the text min or minutes (but not including the words min or minutes). i.e. just the number 12.

Comment: @JohnConde sorry you are correct I should have listed what I have tried, I will ensure on my next posts that I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple regex like this should work:

```
/(\d+) (?:mins|minutes)/
```

The number of minutes will be in the first capture group.

Comment: @Dino, you can get only the digits with my regex by using the first capturing group.  That is preferable to your solution, which uses look-ahead unnecessarily.

Comment: @dan1111 thanks, never knew about capturing groups thanks just researching it online. Appreciate the help and advice.